# install : how to install also subfolders

Tags: installation, makefile

I guess a very basic question, but I fail to find the answer.

In a Makefile, I would like to install files, something like:

```
install:
    # below is invalid, "-R" unsupported
    install -R ./install/include/* $(includedir)
```

here install/include as sub-directories, and I would like all of them to be installed. e.g.

```
./install/a/a.h -> /usr/local/include/a/a.h
./install/b/b.h -> /usr/local/include/b/b.h
```

I fail to find how to do this, and currently I am using instead "cp -R", which comes with complications (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218673/how-is-install-different-from-cp)

Comment: The `install` program has nothing to do with make; this seems to be a question about `install`.  I used `man install` on my system to learn about the options `install` provides and it doesn't appear that it supports recursive directory copy.

Comment: @MadScientist indeed, I removed the reference to make in the title

Comment: The title is not that relevant: on a site the size of SO the important things are the tags; that's what people use to see issues that they may be able to help with etc.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be more of a bash / linux question (I assume its linux)

You can't do recursive install with `install` but you can combine it with something like find:

```sh
includedir=./target_dir/
find ./install/include/ -type f -exec install -Dm 755 "{}" "${includedir}{}" \;
```

This will "install" files from `./install/include/...` to `./target_dir/...` keeping the dir structure. You may want to tweak as required...

### Update

Infact I had a little tinker, you may or may not have the directory structure already in place, so if you need to create the dirs then you might have to split it into two parts (well, that is probably simplest), here is a working example which installs from a sub dir called `source/` to a sub dir called `install/` - change as needed:

```
source = source/
target = install/
    
.PHONY: install
install:
    @for item in $$(find $(source) -type d) ; do install $${item} -d $(target)$${item#$(source)} ; done
    @for item in $$(find $(source) -type f) ; do install $${item} $(target)$${item#$(source)} ; done
```

The first line install the directories

They both replace the top level file so you end up with:

```
install
├── alf
├── fred
├── main
└── sub_dir
    ├── alf2
    ├── fred2
    └── main2
```

instead of

```
install
└── source
    ├── alf
    ├── fred
    ├── main
    └── sub_dir
        ├── alf2
        ├── fred2
        └── main2
```

but tweak as needed